# How to get json data from javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter, tumblr

help, im using tumblr and connect my twitter account, Tumblr gave me this file example:http://titan-theme.tumblr.com/tweets.js

my question is can i get follower_count and screen_name data? if yes how to get it?
please help me
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only this file you should define *recent_tweets* function. Of cours you need to import tweets.js. For example:

```
<script>
    var recent_tweets = function(tweets) {
        for(var i=0; i<tweets.length; i++) {
            var tweet = tweets[i];
            var followerCounts = tweet.user.followers_count;
            var screenName = tweet.user.screen_name;
        }
    }   
</script>
<script src="tweets.js"></script>
```

However, there is no follower_count available.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) file, it needs to be requested via a script tag in order to execute the `recent_tweets` function that encloses it. Try using the jQuery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function (result) {
    callback(result);
  }
});
```